# Retrieving error codes from SQLite when using ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, executenonquery

In my C# project, I'm using `System.Data.SQLite.dll` downloaded from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB%22).

My problem is as per the title - how to get the error codes after calling `SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` function?

Error codes such as `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT, SQLITE_BUSY, SQLITE_LOCKED` as shown [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the Exception.StackTrace or the SQLiteException.ErrorCode

```
try
{

}
catch(SQLiteException ex)
{
    string code = ex.ErrorCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add to this to help others, if you're developing in .NET.  Use the

`SQLiteErrorCode` enumeration to test the result, cast the ErrorCode:

```
try
{

}
catch(SQLiteException ex)
{
    SQLiteErrorCode sqlLiteError= (SQLiteErrorCode)ex.ErrorCode;

    //Do whatever logic necessary based of the error type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question. 
System.Exception does not have a member by the name ".ErrorCode"

```
    Catch Ex As SQLiteException
        E = Ex.ResultCode
        Return E
    End Try
```