# Local MySQL database for C# app

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I'm creating an application that is to be used "in-house" over a local network, that *has* to work when there is no internet.

I initially wanted to do it in Laravel (PHP), but that requires being able to query an online database.

So, I have settled with developing it in C#. There is only one thing I need to be certain of first based on these wishes:

- I want to use MySQL (I have it installed and the C# lib)
- The database needs to be local and shared between instances of the app

*( If there are better options than MySQL for local db handling, I'm open for that as well)*

**Now** for the questions:

1. What are / and how would I package dependencies to be able to use MySQL on any machine installing the app? I want a simple install.
2. What do you believe would be the best way to keep a shared database on a local network, that accepts changes from several instances in real-time?

Some pointers and/or advice would be appreciated. I'm planning the app atm (o'l pen and paper), so this would be the time :)

Best regards,
Oyvind

Comment: Open Nuget Package Manager and get SQLite instead?

Comment: I would have to agree, the simplicity and ease. How "fast" / advanced is it compared to MySQL?

Comment: Can't really say, you have to Google :) But SQLite is serverless so it might fit better for your scenario.

Comment: I like it, and it would suit my needs if it was good for multi-user apps. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems  Gives an indication that I should _not_ use it... Seems legit. A shame really. Might look into SQL Server

Comment: From the above URL: "If you are working on an application whereby multiple clients need to access and use the same database, a fully-featured RDBM (e.g. MySQL) is probably better to choose over SQLite."

Comment: Yeah, it's not easy to choose http://stackoverflow.com/q/15383615/1061668