# C# - Enable Multi-thread mode in SQLite

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, mutex

How to enable Multi-thread mode in SQLite? I am trying to do it in run-time selection but I can't find out how to do it. I was trying with SQLiteConnectionFlags but I can't find flag for it. Can you provide me simple example? I have no idea how to do it with compile-time or start-time selection also.

Official documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: Related Thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383615/multiple-access-to-a-single-sqlite-database-file-via-system-data-sqlite-and-c-sh

Comment: Are you sure it's not on by default?

Comment: The default mode is serialized. I need multi-thread mode.